# how to break numbers in interval

Tags: r

I'm trying to cut credit scores to ranges in order to assign their rating.

I tried this:

```
x <- sample(510:780, 50, replace=TRUE)
cut(x, breaks=c(300, 579, 669, 739, 799), include.lowest=TRUE)
```

result:

```
[300,579] (579,669] (669,739] (739,799]
```

but I want something like:

```
(300, 579] (580, 669] (670, 739] (740,799] (739,799]
```

something like the ranges here: https://www.experian.com/blogs/ask-experian/credit-education/score-basics/what-is-a-good-credit-score/

Comment: Why do you need `(300, 579] (580, 669]... ` ?

Comment: see my solution and hope it is what you want

Comment: @RonakShah see the link in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can try the code below:

```
bks <- c(300, 579, 669, 739, 799)
bks <- sort(c(bks, bks[-c(1,length(bks))]+1))
r <- cut(x, breaks= bks, include.lowest=F)
f <- levels(r)[-seq(2,length(levels(r)),by = 2)]
r <- factor(r[r %in% f])
```

Such that you get:

```
> levels(r)
[1] "(300,579]" "(580,669]" "(670,739]" "(740,799]"
```

Comment: this doesn't give the desired output? OP wants the lower bound in subsequent intervals to be 1 greater than the upper bound in preceding ones...

Comment: @user2474226 thanks for reminder, now the code is updated

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need what you are showing here. Based on which group the data at the intervals should be part of you can use either `findInterval` or `cut` like :

```
findInterval(579, c(300, 579, 669, 739, 799), left.open = TRUE) 
#[1] 1

findInterval(579, c(300, 579, 669, 739, 799))
#[1] 2
```

With `cut`

```
cut(579, c(300, 579, 669, 739, 799))
#[1] (300,579]
#Levels: (300,579] (579,669] (669,739] (739,799]

cut(579, c(300, 579, 669, 739, 799), right = FALSE)
#[1] [579,669)
#Levels: [300,579) [579,669) [669,739) [739,799)
```